# pyarrow.parquet.write_table: memory usage

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

I need to prepare .parquet file using Python, so this is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pandas as pd
import sys
import mysql.connector
import json

def write_table(databaseServer, databaseDatabase, databaseUser, databasePassword, sql, fileName):
    result = 0;
    frame = {};
    convert_to_double = {};

    try:
        database = mysql.connector.connect(host=databaseServer, database=databaseDatabase, user=databaseUser, password=databasePassword)

        try:
            cursor = database.cursor(buffered=False)

            cursor.execute(sql)

            for desc in cursor.description:
                name = desc[0]
                type = desc[1]

                frame[name] = [];

                if mysql.connector.FieldType.get_info(type) == 'NEWDECIMAL':
                    convert_to_double[name] = True;

            records = cursor.fetchall()

            for record in records:
                i = 0;

                for name in cursor.column_names:
                    if name in convert_to_double:
                        frame[name].append(float(record[i]))
                    else:
                        frame[name].append(record[i])

                    i += 1

                result += 1;
        finally:
            cursor.close()
    finally:
        database.close()

    
    if result == 0:
        return result;
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(frame)
    table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
    pq.write_table(table, fileName)

    return result
```

Problem is I don't have much memory on a server, but here in this code I load entire SQL query into columns that stores in memory. Also I cannot partition data to load less data (it's already partitioned by months, I prepare .parquet files por Amazon Athena).

My questions are:

- is it a way to reduce memory usage while preparing .parquet files this way?
- is it a way to query data from database column by column and then write all these columns into single .parquet?
- will it helps to reduce memory usage if I write CSV first on disk and then tell pandas to convert this .csv into .parquet?

Thanks.

Comment: I made some research and found out than making CSV first and then converting this CSV to .parquet reduce memory usage in this case by 60%.

Still wondering if there is any other approach to reduce memory usage by pandas

Answer (score 0):

At the momment you are:

- Loading data into memory (in vectors)
- Converting the data to a df
- Storing the data in parquet

This strategy only works if all the data can be stored in memory.

You could instead write smaller batches of data to the parquet file, using [ParquetWriter](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.ParquetWriter.html#pyarrow.parquet.ParquetWriter)

To answer your quesions one by one:

- You can reduce the memory foot print by using numpy arrays insead of python arrays. They are much more efficient in terms of memory. Also You should not call `fetchall()` but stream records from the cursor instead.
- I don't think there is a way to write parquet file columns by columns. You address the scale issue by writing smaller groups of rows.
- CSV data representation is less efficient than parquet or pandas, I'm not sure it would hep.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answer, I made these modificacions: stream rows from mysql one by one instead of fetchall (this helped a lot) and use ParquetWriter. This reduces memory, but with ParquetWriter i got result parquet file with more size (15-25% depending on chunk size).

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to increase your file size signiifcantly. The recommaned size of chunks to get good performance is 50mb.